# Real Projective Line Question

Tags: geometry

What is an example of a mapping from the Real Projective Line $(RP^1)$ to the Real Projective Line $(RP^1)$. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: $f(RP^1) \to RP^1$

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I'm not sure what your comment is meant to indicate.  Neither does that define a mapping nor is it standard notation.  To OP: An extremely simple example would be the identity map.  Some more non-trivial examples come from taking maps $S^1\rightarrow S^1$ and composing them with the quotient map $S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some help in http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~khudian/Teaching/Manifolds/Manifolds08/cswmansol1008.pdf  if you pay enough attention  (the level is maybe high).